# WSO2 EI 6.6.0 cluster in AWS Fargate

Tags: wso2, aws-fargate, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

hello can you advise me please.
I would like to deploy wso2 EI 6.6.0 in a cluster to aws fargate. is there a similar guide as for aws ec2 https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+Up+a+Cluster+in+AWS+Mode? do you have experience with it please?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying EKS with AWS Fargate, you can use the helm charts available here - https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-ei/tree/v6.6.0.3

If you are planning to use ECS with AWS Fargate, then you will have to create those service definitions using the docker images mentioned in https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-ei/tree/v6.6.0.3